# Laravel BelongsTo relationship is not working after deploy but it works in local machine

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using the model below and it is working normaly in my machine but, after to deploy it in production, it is returning null instead of data user.

```
    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Occurrence extends Model {
       protected $table      = 'occurrences';
       protected $guarded    = [];
       protected $primaryKey = 'id_occurrence';

       public function owner(){

          return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id_user_fk', 'id_user');

       }

       public function department(){

          return $this->belongsTo(Department::class, 'id_department_fk', 'id_department');

       }
    }
```

Both of methods are working im my local machine.

```
    $occurrence = new App\Occurrence;
    => App\Occurrence {#2938}
    >>> $occurrence->first()->owner;
    => App\User {#2947
         id_user: 2,
         name: "Jiripoqueiro",
         email: "jiripoca_vaipiar@yahoo.com.br",
         dateofbirth: "1985-08-15",
         active: 1,
         created_at: "2019-06-03 12:05:50",
         updated_at: "2019-06-03 12:05:50",
       }
```

But when I deploy it, the "owner" method return null.

```
    >>> $occurrence = new App\Occurrence;
    => App\Occurrence {#2970}
    >>> $occurrence->first()->owner;
    => null
```

It is wird because the belongTo relationship to the "department" method is working in both of cases, development and production, but the owner method not.

See the User class below

```
    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
       //protected $guarded = [];
       protected $primaryKey = 'id_user';
       use Notifiable;


        /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $fillable = [
            'name', 'email', 'password',
        ];

        /**
         * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $hidden = [
            'password'
        ];
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you migrated your database too ?

Comment: Hi @VincentDecaux. Yes. I used the Mysql Workbench to mirror my local database to the production server.

Comment: It seems that you dont have data into your tables, check if you have at least one.

Comment: I am feeling so dumb.. @Vrian7 I have data into my tables but I did a double check now and found out that the id_user_fk of the user in "occurrence" table is different from the id_user on table user. It happened because the User table I entered manualy the user with the ID 1, but the same user in occurrence table is 2... anyway, thank you very much lads for your help!!